# Как инициализировать HRGN?

Tags: windows, winapi, c++

Для выполнения требуется инициализация переменной Crgn?

```
CombineRgn(Crgn, hRgn1, hRgn2, RGN_AND);
```

---

Дошло. Его заткнуло пирожком **CreateRectRgn(0,0,0,0)**;
По нелепости и неопытности посчитал что CombineRgn само создаст регион. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо. Но еще не понятно как это. Если можно пример.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Codes/Load-Save-Dib-Bitmap-File-GetScrollPosition-FillRgn-CombineRgn-Create-Cursor.htm). Возможно этот пример поможет. Там комбинируют 2 региона, заменяя первый из них.

Comment: @avp, вы текст не совсем читаете? Где здесь `CRgn::CombineRgn`?!

Comment: @karmadro4, там просто другой интерфейс к тем же мелкософтовским функциям, что автор пользовать пытается. По сути он не понимает, как хэндл получить. 

В доке (на которую Вы ссылку даете) про это умалчивается. 

Вот, пусть посмотрит на аналог и поймет идею.

Comment: @avp, я раскрываю откуда взять дескриптор строкой ниже. Читайте. MFCишный класс-обертка, на который вы зачем-то сослались, создает дескриптор в конструкторах.

Comment: @Димка, это функция в принципе может и создать, но взгляните на сигнатуру, **вернуть** новый HRGN она не сможет никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте [маны](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183465), они рулез!

> hrgnDest [in]
>
> A handle to a new region with dimensions defined by combining two
> other regions. (**This region must exist before CombineRgn is called**.)

Жирнота моя. Регионы создаются функциями [`Create<shape>Rgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183514#see_also).

---

Естественно, инициализация требуется, т.к. дескриптор региона назначения - параметр "in". В этот регион записывается результат операции (текущее содержимое будет перезаписано). Кажущаяся нелогичность с "in" и "out" возникает потому, что API дает доступ только к *непрозрачным* дескрипторам, а не к самим структурам данных.

На мой взгляд не хватает функции (или макро) `HRGN CreateNullRgn(void)`.

Comment: :)))))
Я не сказал что проблема в создании региона. Теперь хотел их скомпоновать, но ИДЕшка требует всё и вся инициализировать. Если при создании это еще можно было то с этой функцией непонятно. Но всё равно СПАСИБО!
Манов до хрена, но еще не разумею, не вижу обычных примеров.

Comment: @Димка, дополнил, надеюсь, стало понятнее. В вашем случае нет никакой разницы как создавать регион назначения, потому что функция содержимое всё равно перезапишет. Сравните дескрипторы с указателями, там используется такая же in/out логика.